# Why there is a - (dash) or an _ (underscore) between <a> images

Tags: html, css

Can somebody explain why I do see 2 dashes (or underscore) between
my images, like this:

[image]

How to remove them ?

This weird behavior appears in chrome (linux), safari (mac) as well in firefox (mac).

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            ul li {
                display: inline;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background: none;">
        <ul clas="">
            <li>
                <a href="file:///dir/file.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is title">
                    <img src="file:///thumbnails/t.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Hi">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="file:///dir/file.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is title">
                    <img src="file:///thumbnails/t.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Hi">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="file:///dir/file.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is title">
                    <img src="file:///thumbnails/t.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Hi">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Write also as `</li><li>` (or as appropriate) - that is, butt the elements up so there is no extra text node. The underline shows an underlying problem.

Comment: they're links. probably spaces caused by the line breaks between `<img></a>`. remember - html rendereres treat line breaks in the html source as whitespace chars and render them as spaces.

Comment: Space between </li> and </i> is of no consequence, its what happens between </i> and </li> that is of importance and down to the rendering engine to solve problems of inconsistency and report it as an error if indeed an error is encountered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not an underscore, it's the underlining of a link.  Note your markup:

```
<a href="file:///dir/file.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is title">
    <img src="file:///thumbnails/t.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Hi">
</a>
```

Before and after the `img` there is whitespace within the `a`.  If `a` elements are styled to be underlined, that whitespace will be underlined.

You can remove the whitespace:

```
<a href="file:///dir/file.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is title"><img src="file:///thumbnails/t.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Hi"></a>
```

and/or you can change the styling:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because it's wrapped in a link. You will have to remove the underline with CSS.

```css
.myListWithoutUnderlines a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

.myListWithoutUnderlines li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="myListWithoutUnderlines">
   <li>
      <a href="file:///dir/file.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is title">
          <img src="file:///thumbnails/t.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Hi">
      </a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="file:///dir/file.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is title">
          <img src="file:///thumbnails/t.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Hi">
      </a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="file:///dir/file.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is title">
          <img src="file:///thumbnails/t.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Hi">
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, how did you add the Run-Copy buttons ?

Comment: you have to use the "insert code snippet button. Or add some inline comments. Just take a look at the markdown by clicking "edit".

Answer (score 2):

just set `text-decoration: none` on `a` tags in your CSS

```
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need this html:

```
<a ...><img /></a>
       ^------^---- no spaces/linebreaks.
```

Line breaks in html source are rendered as space characters. So the standard link/underline display extends PAST your image's edges by the width of the space your line breaks are being rendered as.

Answer (score 1):

The underscores are caused by the browser registering a space after the image, before the closing `</a>` tag. To counteract this, you would need to remove the indentation:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        ul li {
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background: none;">
    <ul class="">
        <li>
            <a href="file:///dir/file.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is title"><img src="file:///thumbnails/t.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Hi"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="file:///dir/file.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is title"><img src="file:///thumbnails/t.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Hi"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="file:///dir/file.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is title"><img src="file:///thumbnails/t.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Hi"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I save my breath to write my own answer. But let me add the bin I've already created: http://jsbin.com/revecabute/1/edit See the first image where the whitespace before and after the image is removed (underscore gone). See the last image where the white space has been removed from the list item too (space gone)

Answer (score 0):

The way your HTML is written, there is space after your `<img>` before the `</a>` which the browser is applying the anchor style to (the underline).

I would actually recommend doing something like (CSS) `a img { display: block; float: left; }`